# Заполнение динамического массива (Java)

Tags: java, массивы

Как правильно заполнить динамический массив данными. Имею следующий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Weight=0;
        int Count=0;
        // we take the same instance of the problem displayed in the image
        System.out.println("Введите грузоподъемность рюкзака и нажмите Enter: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Weight = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите количество вещей и нажмите Enter: ");
        Count = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i=1; i<=Count;i++){
            System.out.println("Введите через запятую ценность и вес "+i+"-ой вещи и нажмите Enter: ");
            String somebody = scan.nextLine();

            String[] somebodyList = somebody.split(",");
            Item[] items = new Item[Integer.parseInt(i+"-я вещь"),toString(somebodyList[0]),toString(somebodyList[1])];

        }

        /*Item[] items = {new Item("Elt1", 4, 12),
                new Item("Elt2", 2, 1),
                new Item("Elt3", 2, 2),
                new Item("Elt4", 1, 1),
                new Item("Elt5", 10, 4)};*/

        Main knapsack = new Main(items, Weight);
        //Main knapsack = new Main(items, 15);
        knapsack.display();
        Solution solution = knapsack.solve();
        solution.display();
    }
```

Когда пытаюсь в цикле организовать заполнение, то сталкиваюсь с ошибками. Что не так. 
P.S. чуть ниже закомментированный код с заранее известными данными.

Comment: "сталкиваюсь с ошибками" - ??

Comment: Во-первых, для "динамичности" лучше использовать списки, а не массивы. Во-вторых, вам нужно разобраться с областями видимости. В-третьих, вы зачем-то на каждой итерации создаёте новый массив, затирая ссылку на старый, вместо его заполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо разобраться в динамических массивах.

Например, `int[] array = new int[10];` - это статический массив, потому что в нём необходимо задать размер сразу же. В вашем случае происходит переинициализация массива, т.е. сначала создаёте массив, а при новой итерации в цикле `for` вы опять **заново** создаёте.

`private List<Integer> x = new ArrayList();` - это уже является динамическим, потому что размерность не задаём, он будет расширяться по мере заполнения данными.

Comment: Хорошо. Буду смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, выглядит так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Weight=0;
        int Count=0;

        System.out.println("Введите грузоподъемность рюкзака и нажмите Enter: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Weight = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите количество вещей и нажмите Enter: ");
        Count = scan.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Вводим параметры вещей");
        for (int i=1; i<=Count;i++){
            System.out.println("Введите через запятую ценность и вес "+i+"-ой вещи и нажмите Enter: ");
            arrayList.add(scan.next());
            }

        Item[] items = new Item[Count];

        for (int i=0;i<Count;i++){
            String s = arrayList.get(i);
            String[] wordlist = s.split(",");
            items[i] = new Item("Вещь "+(i+1), Integer. parseInt(wordlist[0]), Integer. parseInt(wordlist[1]));
        }


        Main knapsack = new Main(items, Weight);
        knapsack.display();
        Solution solution = knapsack.solve();
        solution.display();
    }
```